# Segmentation Fault SQLite Backup

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, backup, database-backups

I want to backup the SQLite database from my file system to in memory database using C++. I read this [website](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) and try the example 1. It compiled perfectly but I get an error "Segmentation Fault". The code looks like this:

Ps: The last line `printf("foo1");` is not printed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int count, char **data, char **column) {
   int i;
   int lastEntry = count - 1;

   printf("{");
   for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
      if (i == lastEntry ) {
         printf("\"%s\" : \"%s\"", column[i], data[i] ? data[i] : "NULL");
      } else {
         printf("\"%s\" : \"%s\",", column[i], data[i] ? data[i] : "NULL");
      }
   }
   printf("}\n");
   return 0;
}


int loadOrSaveDb(sqlite3 *pFile, const char *zFilename, int isSave){
  int rc;                   /* Function return code */
  sqlite3 *pInMemory;           /* Database connection opened on zFilename */
  sqlite3_backup *pBackup;  /* Backup object used to copy data */
  sqlite3 *pTo;             /* Database to copy to (pFile or pInMemory) */
  sqlite3 *pFrom;           /* Database to copy from (pFile or pInMemory) */

  /* Open the database file identified by zFilename. Exit early if this fails
  ** for any reason. */
  rc = sqlite3_open(zFilename, &pFile);
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){

    pFrom = (isSave ? pInMemory : pFile);
    pTo   = (isSave ? pFile     : pInMemory);

    pBackup = sqlite3_backup_init(pTo, "main", pFrom, "main");
    if( pBackup ){
      (void)sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);
      (void)sqlite3_backup_finish(pBackup);
    }
    printf("foo");
    rc = sqlite3_errcode(pTo);
  }

  /* Close the database connection opened on database file zFilename
  ** and return the result of this function. */
  (void)sqlite3_close(pFile);
  return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   string sql;

   /* Open Database */
 
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   /* Create SQL Statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
      "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
      "name           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
      "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
      "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
      "SALARY         REAL );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }

   /* Insert SQL statement */
   sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY "  \
         "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 ); " \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY "  \
         "VALUES (2, 'Allen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 ); "     \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY " \
         "VALUES (3, 'Teddy', 23, 'Norway', 20000.00 );" \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY " \
         "VALUES (4, 'Mark', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }

   /* Select SQL statement */
   //sql = "SELECT * from COMPANY WHERE NAME LIKE 'Paul'";
   sql = "SELECT * from COMPANY";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }

   loadOrSaveDb(db, "test.db", 0);
   
   sqlite3_close(db);
   printf("foo1");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The destination for `sqlite3_backup_init` has to be a [database connection handle](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/sqlite3.html). In order to use `sqlite3 *pInMemory;` as the destination, you should initialise it with such a handle:

```
sqlite3 *pInMemory;           /* Database connection opened on zFilename */
sqlite3_open(":memory:", &pInMemory);
```